# Prevent Hibernate from generating EmbeddedID

Tags: hibernate

I am a novice in hibernate so please excuse me if the question is wrong or naive...

I have some tables in the database which do not have primary key or any kind of key...

Now when i am reverse engineering using eclipse, then i am getting all the tables as java classes, but i am also getting classes with Id appended in them and all the columns in the Id appended class and not in the main class. For Example.

Table1 in database has columns listed below
1. name varchar(200)
2. age int

So now when i am running hibernate reverse engineering in eclipse i am getting classes like this

```
class Table1
{
    private Table1ID;
}
```

and

```
class Table1ID
{
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
}
```

where as i do not want in this manner...
i only want as below

```
class Table1
{
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
}
```

Please guide me how can i achieve this without introducing an Primary Key column in table

Answer (score 1):

With [hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-declaration-id) you need to have a primary key with your entity. No alternative.